# Numeric keyboard with dot instead of comma for IP address input

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an iOS and Android app using Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.3693], locale de-DE).

I have a TextFormField for IP address input:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: const TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
  controller: _ipAddressController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
    hintText: MyLocalizations.of(context)!.ipAddressHintText,
    labelText: MyLocalizations.of(context)!.ipAddress),
  inputFormatters: [
    LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15),
    IpAddressInputFormatter(),
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp('[0-9.]'))
  ],
)
```

The input formatters work fine so far. No issues.

My problem is the `keyboardType`.
On a Pixel5, Pixel6a and an older Samsung tablet everything is fine, also on an iPad, but on an iPhone the keyboard shows numbers and a comma as separator, not a dot. So I can't enter IP addresses on an iPhone.

In my input formatter I tried to replace the comma with a dot which works quite well. But the keyboard still shows the comma which is kind of awkward to tap on a comma when I want to enter a dot.

I don't want to switch back to the "normal" keyboard with all the letters, since only IP addresses are allowed.

I found the package [keyboard_actions](https://pub.dev/packages/keyboard_actions) and I'm thinking of writing my own custom keyboard to have it look consistent across devices, operating systems, versions, languages, etc.

Is there an easier way of having a numeric keyboard with dots suitable for entering IP addresses?
Or at least to come up with a full keyboard in "number" mode?

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do that. Another thing you could do is create 4 TextFormField along with 3 TEXT(".") inside a row, there would be no need to use the "." of the keyboard, something that looks like: [127].[0].[0].[1]

Comment: like options 1: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQtDo.png